# Extract chunk of text between symbols from file using Python

Tags: python, regex, extract

I have a txt file that looks something like this:

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n

data report

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n

\n

\n

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n

data report

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n

\n

\n
```

...and so forth

I want to be able to extract each data report and do a variety of things to it (such as print a specific # that sits as a key value in some other dictionary I have, write it to another file, etc.). How would I go about doing this? I've been trying to learn Regex to help out, but it's been confusing as I'm new to python, please help!

Comment: you should show us your `code` so that we can help you correct it..

Comment: It doesn't look like you'd need regex; can't you just split on `=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip NullUserException! If I do that though, won't it create values in the list that are = to newlines? As I said...I'm new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the entire file into a string, split on the =-=-=... string, and strip the leading and trailing whitespace off of your reports like this:

```
s = open(filename).read()
reports = [x.strip() for x in s.split('=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n')]
```

Comment: AWESOME! You're the man. One issue is that I get values in the list that are equal to empty strings ('') between the reports. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Add an `if len(x) > 0` just before the closing square bracket.

Comment: Like this: `reports = [x.strip() for x in s.split('=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n') if len(x) > 0]`

Comment: hrm, didn't seem to work out for me in the shell, but looks like it would be easy to define a function that would do this and run the module. Once again, thanks a lot for this man, this is going to help me out a lot...I think I over-complicated this part of the problem, though I'll probably have to use Regex for the next part, which is extracting certain pieces of information from each report...might ask questions about that later!